# Can "if" statements be used in a PyMC deterministic function?

Tags: python, statistics, pymc, pymc3

After reading Cam Davidson-Pilon's [Probabilistic Programming & Bayesian Methods for Hackers](https://camdavidsonpilon.github.io/Probabilistic-Programming-and-Bayesian-Methods-for-Hackers/), I've decided to try my hand at a Hidden Markov Model (HMM) **learning problem** with PyMC. So far, the code is not cooperating, but through troubleshooting, I feel that I have narrowed down the source of the issue.

Breaking down the code into smaller chunks and focusing on the initial probability and emission probabilities at t=0, I am able learn the emission/observation parameters of a single state at time t=0. However, once I add in another state (for a total of two states), the results of the parameter learning are identical (and incorrect) regardless of data input. So, I feel that I must have done something wrong in the `@pm.deterministic` portion of the code, which is not allowing me to sample from the `Init` initial probability function.

With this portion of code, I am aiming to learn the **initial probability** `p_bern` and **emission probabilities** `p_0` and `p_1` corresponding to states 0 and 1, respectively. The emission is conditional on the state, which is what I am trying to express with my `@pm.deterministic` function. Can I have the "if" statement in this determinstic function? It seems to be the root of the problem.

```
# This code is to test the ability to discern between two states with emissions

import numpy as np
import pymc as pm
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

N = 1000
state = np.zeros(N)
data = np.zeros(shape=N)

# Generate data
for i in range(N):
    state[i] = pm.rbernoulli(p=0.3)
for i in range(N):
    if state[i]==0:
        data[i] = pm.rbernoulli(p=0.4)
    elif state[i]==1:
        data[i] = pm.rbernoulli(p=0.8)

# Prior on probabilities
p_bern = pm.Uniform("p_S", 0., 1.)
p_0 = pm.Uniform("p_0", 0., 1.)
p_1 = pm.Uniform("p_1", 0., 1.)

Init = pm.Bernoulli("Init", p=p_bern) # Bernoulli node

@pm.deterministic
def p_T(Init=Init, p_0=p_0, p_1=p_1, p_bern=p_bern):
    if Init==0:
        return p_0
    elif Init==1:
        return p_1

obs = pm.Bernoulli("obs", p=p_T, value=data, observed=True)
model = pm.Model([obs, p_bern, p_0, p_1])
mcmc = pm.MCMC(model)
mcmc.sample(20000, 10000)
pm.Matplot.plot(mcmc)
```

I have already attempted the following to no avail:

1. Use a `@pm.potential` decorator to [create a joint distribution](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/56543/pymc-how-can-i-define-a-function-of-two-stochastic-variables-with-no-closed-fo)
2. Changing the placement of my `Init` location (you can see my comment in the code where I am unsure of where to put it)
3. Use a `@pm.stochastic` similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23453232/learning-discrete-hmm-parameters-in-pymc)

Edit: As per Chris's suggestion, I've moved the Bernoulli node outside of the deterministic. I've also updated the code to a simpler model (Bernoulli observation instead of multinomial) for easier troubleshooting.

Thank you for your time and attention. Any feedback is warmly received. Also, if I am missing any information please let me know!

Answer (score 2):

I would move this stochasticity out of the deterministic. A deterministic node's value is supposed to be completely determined by the value of its parents. Having a random variable buried in the node violates this.

Why dot create a Bernoulli node, and pass that as an argument to the deterministic?

Comment: Hi @Chris, thanks so much for taking a look at my code. Are you referring to moving `Init = pm.rbernoulli(p=p_bern)` out of the deterministic and passing that as an argument like `if Init==0:`? If so, I've attempted that approach as you can see with the #'ed line in the priors with the same results. Or do you mean something else?

Comment: That's the line. It results in the deterministic node no longer being deterministic.

Comment: So logically does that mean that there's nothing wrong with using `if` statements in a deterministic?

Comment: You can use `if` statements. You just want to avoid embedding stochastic elements in deterministic nodes. `if` is still deterministic when the condition is passed as an argument.

Comment: That's very useful information, thanks. Now when I do this, the posterior of `p_bern` (parameter of `Init`) does not update -- it still shows a uniform posterior, while those of `p_0` and `p_1` do. This results in both `p_0` and `p_1` sharing similar Gaussian distributions, effectively both learning the same single parameter. Any idea how I can make sure `p_bern` updates too?

Comment: Can you update the model above to reflect these changes?

Comment: Yes, in the above code I moved the `Init = pm.Bernoulli("Init", p=p_bern)` outside of the deterministic. Or maybe I misunderstood what you meant to avoid embedding stochastic elements in deterministic nodes?

Answer (score 2):

Based the updated information you have provided, here is some code that works:

```
import numpy as np
import pymc as pm
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

N = 1000
state = np.zeros(N)
data = np.zeros(shape=N)

# Generate data
state = pm.rbernoulli(p=0.3, size=N)
data = [int(pm.rbernoulli(0.8*s or 0.4)) for s in state]

# Prior on probabilities
p_S = pm.Uniform("p_S", 0., 1.)
p_0 = pm.Uniform("p_0", 0., 1.)
p_1 = pm.Uniform("p_1", 0., 1.)

# Use values of Init as indices to probabilities
Init = pm.Bernoulli("Init", p=p_S, size=N) # Bernoulli node

p_T = pm.Lambda('p_T', lambda p_0=p_0, p_1=p_1, i=Init: np.array([p_0, p_1])[i.astype(int)])

obs = pm.Bernoulli("obs", p=p_T, value=data, observed=True)
model = pm.MCMC(locals())
model.sample(20000, 10000)
model.summary()
```

Notice in the data generation step, I am using the states to index the appropriate true probability. I essentially do the same thing in the specification of `p_T`. It appears to work reasonably well, but note that depending on where things get initialized, the two values of `p_0` and `p_1` can end up corresponding to either of the true values (there is nothing to constrain one to be larger than the other). So, the value of `p_S` can end up as the complement of the true state probability.

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for your help. Your method of indexing using the state is very helpful. Practically, is there any difference in your data generation vs mine? Or is it a matter of efficiency? Also, I find your method of using an array to specify `p_T` very cool. Why did you choose this method instead of using an `if` statement?